# How to add a last tag in new line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to Payment Remaining add a new line, but Payment Remaining not come to the new line.

I want to add the last text in a new line **Payment Remaining**

```css
#authorization-wizard-start-work .btn-group label.active {
  color: #0094ff;
}

#authorization-wizard-start-work .btn-group label.active {
  color: #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<main class="col-4 text-right pt-3">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm btn-xs font-weight-bold menu-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fal fa-sliders-h mr-2"></i>&nbsp;Filters</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-3 listing-filter">
      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="0">
                    Payment New 
                    </label>
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="100">
                    Payment In Progress
                    </label>
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="99999">
                    Payment Deleted
                    </label>
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="900">
                    Payment Authorized
                    </label>
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="200">
                    Payment Submission
                    </label>
          <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="300">
                    Payment Remaining
                    </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add minimal code examples (include CSS). No way to answer this. In general use you could use display: block (For "Remaining" label) - or - flexbox - or <br> before (And a lot more ideas - this is why you Q is general).

Comment: @EzraSiton I add the <br/> tag before the last input tag ```<br />
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="300">```

Comment: @ Ezra Siton I edited my question i add a css file plzz help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. You shouldn't be putting the `input` inside the `label` and to get each `input label` pair to have combined CSS, you should child them to a shared class.

See this simple example:

```css
#authorization-wizard-start-work .btn-group label.active {
    color: #0094ff;
}

#authorization-wizard-start-work .btn-group label.active {
    color: #0094ff;
}

.field {
    display: inline-block;
}

.field:last-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs"> Payment 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs"> Payment 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs"> Payment 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="btn btn-white btn-sm btn-xs"> Payment last</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="filter-auth-status" value="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still last payment not add new line  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qbV6.png and see code image https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6npX.png what I m doing wrong

Comment: in the inspector (F12) look at the last element and see what rule is being applied to it as it is overriding the rule you want

Comment: the `label input` pair parents haven't got the `.field` class

Answer (score 0):

simply use br tag before Payment Remaining label tag

Comment: I already try this but not work see my above comment using <br/> tag